# Copying a single object, but transfers whole scene all together

Tags: interface, export, import

Quick question, I have 2 scenes, one from which I want to copy the camera alone, but when I do copy-paste it transfers the whole scene together with the camera.

What I do is copy and paste the camera into the new scene, and it doesn't appear but it's in Scene.001 I have to go there remove everything, and take the camera, which makes my .blend file unnecessarily big.

Hope I do sound clear on what I am trying to say here. If you have a quick solution would be great, thanks.

also, I tried this single-user thing with Hotkey U but doesn't do a thing.

link from the comment below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AGcR24mrB6iVzIxbB7j41TNx_FTDJi3s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: maybe you can make a short screen recording how you are doing that? i can copy paste a camera alone with no problems at all.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AGcR24mrB6iVzIxbB7j41TNx_FTDJi3s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That is okay, but this happened only to the current camera from the current scene, and it has happened multiple times before as well in other "projects" that I have been doing. So it's quite annoying, cause I remake the scene multiple times so I do the whole copy-paste a lot. And it happens only when I copy the camera. For the rest of the objects, it's working fine.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a video or screenshots to see the complete program window including menus etc.? But anyway, as far as I can see you have constraints and animations with drivers on the camera. When you copy an object that is dependent on other objects, these objects will be copied as well to keep those relationships functional. This does not happen if you duplicate the camera with `Shift`+`D`, because there the relations are relative and use the existing objects. With `Ctrl`+`C` they are absolute, even pasting the camera in the same scene will additionally paste the related objects.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Fixed! Thanks

Comment: @ahkai Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: Have you tried to Append instead of copy-pasting? Menu File > Append, navigate in the source file > Objects subfolder > your camera

Comment: That's another way yeah!  @L0Lock

Answer (score 1):

Try to *Append* instead of copy-pasting:

Menu File > Append, navigate in the source file > Objects subfolder > your camera

[image: append window]

Learn more on [Link & Append — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/link_append.html#append).